# NPE in SubqueryImpl from OpenJPA2.2.2

Tags: jpa, openjpa, criteria-api, websphere-8

Can anybody help with a NullPointerException within OpenJPA2.2.2's SubqueryImpl class when using Criteria Builder?   The code works great with EclipseLink on WebSphere Liberty, but fails with NPE within OpenJPA2.2.2 on WebSphere8.5.5.

The code uses CriteriaBuilder to build a subquery against (self) the same table, in order to pull rows with a max(timestamp).

---

**stacktrace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.SubqueryImpl.getCandidate(SubqueryImpl.java:319)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.SubqueryImpl.toValue(SubqueryImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.Expressions.toValue(Expressions.java:66)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.Expressions$Equal.toKernelExpression(Expressions.java:852)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.PredicateImpl.toKernelExpression(PredicateImpl.java:172)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.CriteriaExpressionBuilder.evalFilter(CriteriaExpressionBuilder.java:216)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.CriteriaExpressionBuilder.getQueryExpressions(CriteriaExpressionBuilder.java:75)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl.getQueryExpressions(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:418)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilderImpl.eval(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:83)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery$DataStoreExecutor.<init>(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:763)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.newDataStoreExecutor(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:179)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.createExecutor(QueryImpl.java:749)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForDataStore(QueryImpl.java:707)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:689)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.getOperation(QueryImpl.java:1529)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.getOperation(DelegatingQuery.java:124)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:118)
*   at com.company.pc.connectedcar.api.trip.dao.TripDAO.getTripsByDriverId(TripDAO.java:228)
*   at com.company.pc.connectedcar.api.trip.facade.TripFacade.getTripsForDriver(TripFacade.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5730)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:568)
    at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.common.interceptor.OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.callInterceptorsAndDecorators(OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.java:526)
    at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.common.interceptor.OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.callToOwbInterceptors(OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.java:200)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:548)
    at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.WSEJBInterceptor.callToOwbInterceptors(WSEJBInterceptor.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:548)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInvoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invoke(EJSContainer.java:5621)
*   at com.company.pc.connectedcar.api.trip.facade.EJSLocalNSLTripFacade_b060b6a6.getTripsForDriver(EJSLocalNSLTripFacade_b060b6a6.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.common.proxy.EjbBeanProxyHandler.invoke(EjbBeanProxyHandler.java:204)
*   at com.company.pc.connectedcar.api.trip.facade.TripFacade_$$_javassist_6.getTripsForDriver(TripFacade_$$_javassist_6.java)
*   at com.company.pc.connectedcar.api.trip.resource.TripResource.getTripsForDriver(TripResource.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
*   at com.company.inf.ws.rs2.service.handler.COMPANYWinkServiceHandler.handleRequest(COMPANYWinkServiceHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:188)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:124)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

---

**DAO**

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<TripEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(TripEntity.class);

Root<TripEntity> tripRoot = criteriaQuery.from(TripEntity.class);
criteriaQuery.select(tripRoot);

Path<Timestamp> pathPkTimestamp = tripRoot.<Timestamp> get(COL_TRIP_RECORD_TS);

// Create Predicates for use in the where clause
List<Predicate> predicateList = new LinkedList<Predicate>();

// Predicate DriverId
Predicate predicateDriverId = criteriaBuilder.equal(tripRoot.<String> get(COL_DRIVER_ID), driverId);
predicateList.add(predicateDriverId);

// Subquery to fetch by Max Trip Timestamp
Subquery<Timestamp> sq = criteriaQuery.subquery(Timestamp.class);
Root<TripEntity> tripRoot2 = criteriaQuery.from(TripEntity.class);
Path<Timestamp> pathPkTimestamp2 = tripRoot2.<Timestamp> get(COL_TRIP_RECORD_TS);

sq.select(criteriaBuilder.greatest(pathPkTimestamp2));
sq.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(tripRoot2.get(COL_TRIP_ID), tripRoot.get(COL_TRIP_ID)));

Predicate predicateSubQuery = criteriaBuilder.equal(pathPkTimestamp, sq);
predicateList.add(predicateSubQuery);

// Predicate startDate
if (startDate != null)
{
    Timestamp startTimestamp = new Timestamp(startDate.getTime());
    Predicate predicateStartDate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(pathPkTimestamp, startTimestamp);

    predicateList.add(predicateStartDate);
}

// Predicate endDate
if (endDate != null)
{
    Timestamp endTimestamp = new Timestamp(endDate.getTime());
    Predicate predicateEndDate = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(pathPkTimestamp, endTimestamp);
    predicateList.add(predicateEndDate);
}

// Set Where clause criteria from Predicate List
Predicate[] predicateArray = new Predicate[predicateList.size()];
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(predicateArray)));

// Set Order by
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(tripRoot.get(COL_TRIP_RECORD_TS)));
```

---

**Entity snippet**

```
@IdClass(TripEntityPK.class)
public class TripEntity implements Serializable
{

private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "OBFUSCATED...._UUID")
private String              tripId;

@Id
@Column(name = "OBFUSCATED....C_TS")
private Timestamp           tripRecordTs;

@Column(name = "OBFUSCATED...._UUID")
private String              driverId;

@Column(name = "OBFUSCATED...._TS")
private Timestamp           driverRecordTs;

...
```

---

Comment: It would be better to post a little more about the exception. Post atleast 3-4 levels of exception not just the last one.

Comment: I added a longer stack trace, that shows the stack from the incoming REST request, serviced by WebSphere, and traversing down to the DAO layer to the JPA call.

Answer (score 0):

The NPE comes from getting the root to the subquery table incorrectly, such that the subquery didn't have it's own root.

```
// incorrect
Root<TripEntity> tripRoot2 = criteriaQuery.from(TripEntity.class);

// corrected code
Root<TripEntity> tripRoot2 = sq.from(TripEntity.class);
```